# Solve for x (quadratic equation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals, substitution, nested-radicals

How do you solve the following equation:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2017 + \sqrt{2017 - x}} &= x
\end{align*}

I tried squaring it twice, but then I am left with quadratic equation that I can not solve.

Comment: it must be $$0\le x\le 2017$$

Comment: You have quadratic equation in your title, yet you haven't ....... your equation. (Fill in the blanks.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $2017-x=y^2$, where $y\geq0$.

Hence, $x+y>0$ and $2017+y=x^2$, which gives $y+x=x^2-y^2$ or $x-y=1$ and the rest is smooth.
We have $y=x-1$, $2017+x-1=x^2$ or $$x^2-x-2016=0$$ and since $x>0$, 
we get the answer $\{\frac{1+\sqrt{8065}}{2}\}$.

Comment: Then how to solve it further?

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh I fixed my post for you.

Comment: y=x-1 and you directly write $2017+x-1=x^2$. How?

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh Because $2017+y=x^2$.

Comment: Probably a typo : $8085$ should be $8065$ (I guess).

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

after squaring we will get
$$\sqrt{2017-x}=x^2-2017$$
squaring one more times we obtain
$$0=x^4-4034x^2+x-2017+2017^2$$
the solution is given by $$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{8065}\right)$$

Comment: How can we get the said solution from $x^4 - ... =0$?

Comment: it can be factorized into $$\left(x^2-x-2016\right) \left(x^2+x-2017\right)$$

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1)  How to group the terms (or insert auxiliary terms) so that it can be factorized as such? 2) Why are the other 3 roots ignored? Is it because you have verified already?